# Updating active directory with PHP?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am working on a system that shows employee information from Active Directory. Part of it allows the user to update their own information, (title, firstname, lastname, email, telephonenumber, title, company, department) and so forth. I have the following PHP code (if it is relevant):

```
function updateActiveDirectory($user, $first, $last, $mail, $number, $title, $service, $team)
{
    /* This function, similar to the above one, but this will update Active Directory. We need to make sure that, even if the fields are empty, they still contain some character */
    if(empty($first)==TRUE)
    {
        $first = "    ";
    }
    if(empty($last)==TRUE)
    {
        $last = "    ";
    }
    if(empty($mail)==TRUE)
    {
        $mail = "    ";
    }
    if(empty($number)==TRUE)
    {
        $number = "    ";
    }
    if(empty($team)==TRUE)
    {
        $team = "    ";
    }
    if(empty($service)==TRUE)
    {
        $service = "    ";
    }
    if(empty($title)==TRUE)
    {
        $title = "    ";
    }
    $server    = "DC-1";
    /* The path to the OU we are working in */
    $unit         = "OU=Staff,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com";
    $ds             = ldap_connect($server);
    if(!$ds)
    {
        return "Cannot connect to LDAP server";
    }
    $bind = ldap_bind($ds, "DOMAIN\dirplus", "P@55w0rd3=");
    /* Bind to a given user */
    if(!$bind)
    {
        return "Couldn't bind to LDAP server";
    }
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    $sr = ldap_search($ds, $unit, "(sAMAccountName={$user})");
    $ent= ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
    $userdata = array();
    //$userdata["cn"][0]=$first. " ".$last;
    $userdata["sn"][0]=$last;
    $userdata["mail"][0]=$mail;
    $userdata["telephonenumber"][0]=$number;
    $userdata["company"][0]=$service;
    $userdata["department"][0]=$team;
    $userdata["title"][0]=$title;
    $name = $ent[0]["dn"];
    $modify = ldap_modify($ds, $name, $userdata);
    if($modify==TRUE)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I have tried giving the account every delagated permission I can think of, even giving it rights for the entire directory, but I get an insufficient access error. This would be fine since I have it set to be administrator but I am being told I cannot do this anymore for some compliance type reason.

I do not know what to do and I am not finding any decent resources on the Internet.

Comment: What do you mean you have set it to be administrator? What is your actual question here? As a side note [`ldap_modify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-modify.php) returns either TRUE or FALSE so you might as well just `return $modify`.

Comment: I mean I have set the "dirplus" account to be a domain administrator. It updates active directory when the "dirplus" account is a domain administrator but not when I attempt to delegate permissions to it

Comment: Did you check the object you've been trying to change? Just as an example domain admin accounts would/could have broken inheritance. So while you did set the permissions on the OU it might actually not apply to the specific user object.

Comment: Not entirely sure how to do that so, what you're saying is, if I create a new account and delegate all permissions to it then it should work

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that depending on which objects you're calling `ldap_modify` for you might not be able to change them even if you do have the permissions on the OU as e.g. their inheritance might be broken. So do you have a problem for EVERY user object you're trying to modify or just for some?

Comment: I am getting the error on all of them

Comment: Did you try to start the AD console using the other credentials and change a user? If that work you'd know that your code and not the permissions are a problem. Also consider `ldap_errno()` maybe that would get you more insight/a better error indicator than a general permission denied. You're right that you would have to setup permissions for that user. I'm not sure about delegation otherwise right clicking on a OU and setting up the permission should help. There are lots of options for it so you will have to check which ones you need.

Comment: Are you sure that \d is valid? $bind = ldap_bind($ds, "DOMAIN\dirplus", "***");